# Reload the first data-role="page" from other data-role="page"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form with three different `data-role="page"` with three different `data-url="abc".`

Based on some condition I am rendering/displaying **some fields** on the second page after clicking the button on the first page.

Now I am getting the second page

```
<a id="123" class="xxx" href="#secondPageId" data-role="button">GoToNextScreen</a>
```

Now in the second page URL i can able to see http://www.test.com/index.html#secondPageId

when i am in the second page If i refresh the browser,

Its showing all available controls in the second page.

But i need to **display only few fields** based on the button click.

How can i do that ?

If that is not possible, then:

While refreshing the browser by clicking "Browser Refresh button" or Pressing F5 I need to remove the #secondPageId from the URL.

So that i can able to go back to first page.

Comment: You can redirect to first page on refresh using `window.location.href = "firstpageURL";`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zady4yqp/2/) that illustrates a possible solution.
Basically, you can do this in two ways:

1. Initially hide all elements and use jQuery to show the required ones at pagechange.
2. Initially hide nothing at all, and use jQuery to hide the required elements at pagechange.

The fiddle uses the latter one.

**HTML**:

```
<div data-role="page" id="first">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h3>
      First Page
      <a id='Goto_page2' class='ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>NEXT</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>
      Please go to next page.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="second">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h3>
      Second Page
      <a href='#first' class='ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>HOME</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div>
      <p class="tobehidden">
        This text was visible, but has been made hidden.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div> 
      <p>
        This text only is visible.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tobehidden"> 
      <h4>
        This text was also visible, but has now been made hidden.
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  //Change to first page at load
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#first");

  /* 
   * Read more about page handling here: 
   * http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change
   */

  //Click event for the "NEXT" button
  $( document ).on("click", "#Goto_page2", function(){

    //Hide elements that has the class "tobehidden"
    $(".tobehidden").hide();

    //Switch to page 2
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#second");
  });
});
```